# repeat the row n times with a separator in-line

Tags: text-processing

I'd like to repeat the row n times with a separator in-line (i.e. not generate extra rows). E.g. for the file example.csv with two rows

```
0.1\r\n
0.2\r\n
```

The result for n=3 and comma as a separator would be

```
0.1,0.1,0.1\r\n
0.2,0.2,0.2\r\n
```

I tried it with a paste command for n=2:

```
paste -d, example.csv example.csv
```

However, the EOLs are pasted too:

```
0.1\r,0.1\r\n
0.2\r,0.2\r\n
```

Comment: Are those literal `\r\n`? i.e. four literal characters?

Comment: @Sparhawk I meant "\r\n" as end-of-line, not literal characters

Comment: For me, your `paste` command works well. You might have an issue due to `\r\n` being [Windows line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them). Run `dos2unix example.csv example_unix.csv` and then `paste -d, example_unix.csv example_unix.csv`

Comment: @RoVo ... and n times?

Comment: So in the final code block, are you using a combination of interpreted newlines and literal newlines? Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Sparhawk in the final code block I showed my try. First, it needs to avoid repeating EOLs (looks like dos2unix is the way to go). Second, it needs to be extended from 2 to n. Maybe also there are better ways than "paste"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you fixed your line endings with

```
dos2unix example.csv
```

You can use `printf` to repeat the filename `n` times.

```
paste -d, $(printf 'example.csv %.0s' {1..10})
```

or if `$n` is a variable use `seq` instead of brace expansion:

```
paste -d, $(printf 'example.csv %.0s' $(seq 1 $n))
```

([via](https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is no requirement to keep line ends as is and it can be converted to unix style do that as first step:

```
dos2unix file
```

For second step use `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=3;i++){if(i>1)printf ",";printf $0};printf "\n"}'
```

awk will in cycle construct the string putting there as many repetitions as you specify in `i<=3` part.

`if` is required to ensure that you have `,` only between repetitions.

end result will be unix-style output. you might convert it back to dos if you need with `unix2dos`.